# ActiveMQ Transport Thread is not terminated when main ends

Tags: java, multithreading, activemq-classic

This is how I start connection:

```
factory = new PooledConnectionFactory(brokerURL);

brokerURL is "failover:(tcp://host1.com:61616,tcp://host2.com:61616)?randomize=false&jms.useAsyncSend=false&jms.dispatchAsync=false&maxReconnectAttempts=30&maxReconnectDelay=3000"
```

Connection is started:

```
connection = factory.createConnection("", ""); 
connection.start();
```

Application performs its usual tasks before connections gets closed:

```
connection.close();
```

main method is finished, but JVM is not, because there are still a few ActiveMQ threads active:

```
Thread [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://host1.com/ip_address:61616@2455] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor ReadCheckTimer] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor WriteCheckTimer] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [ActiveMQ InactivityMonitor Worker] (Running)
```

How am I supposed to close it so that the threads above will shutdown too.
ActiveMQ version 5.10.0

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with (PooledConnectionFactory) factory).stop();

Answer (score 0):

Or add "daemon=true" as a connection url parameter.

As per http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html

> If true the transport thread will run in daemon mode

The main JVM thread will exit even if daemon threads are running.