# ActiveMQ stale client connection when broker is down

Tags: docker, activemq-classic

Using ActiveMQ Docker Image: rmohr/activemq

My application has made a connection to the ActiveMQ instance running in the Docker container and it is able to receive the message successfully. However, if I stop my Docker container the ActiveMQ connection in the application does not die out or throw any new exception. I have waited for 15 minute, but it has not died.

Is there anyway or parameter which can control the ActiveMQ connection behaviour?

Comment: Just to add more information, I am using default parameter for activemq. I have also looked at https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/client-reconnection.html
But it was not very much helpful to me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695079/activemq-transport-thread-is-not-terminated-when-main-ends

Comment: Thanks @LinPy But that question is about threads still been active even after main exit. In my case, application is still running, it is the server which goes down.

Comment: Are you using ActiveMQ 5.x or ActiveMQ Artemis? The [docker image you're using](https://hub.docker.com/r/rmohr/activemq/) looks like it's for 5.x, but [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.0.0/client-reconnection.html) you cited is for Artemis.

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes, you are right. I was looking at wrong documentation. Anyway, I found the solution.

Comment: If you've found the solution please mark your answer as correct so it's clear for people who may run into this same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution which works for me 
http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-auto-reconnection

Adding `failover` in broker url ensures that whenever server goes up, it will reconnect it immediately. 
I have tested this in two ways and in both cases application is able to connect to the server properly. 
Test :

- Stopping active mq server while application is running.
- Starting the application while active mq server is stopped